# Macro wont copy and paste worksheets to another workbook on a server location

Tags: excel, vba

Been working on a macro to copy sheets from the main workbook and to paste them into a temporary workbook in another location to save as a workbook and add to email for sending before deleting it.

I finally cracked it last night and it works great on my machine (Excel 2013) but when I took it to work and put on my machine there and changed the folder destinations to their respective locations on our shared drive (Excel 2010) the macro freezes at the copy/paste part of the macro and I cant figure out why?
As said the below works fine on my PC.

```
{Sub LatestUpdates()
 
    Dim FName           As String
    Dim FPath           As String
    Dim NewBook         As Workbook
    Dim Ws              As Worksheet
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 
    FPath = "C:\Temp"
    FName = "Latest Spreadsheet for Details" & " " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
 
    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
 
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", "Sheet6", "Sheet7", _
        "Sheet8", "Sheet9", "Sheet10")).Copy Before:=NewBook.Sheets(1)
        
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete
    Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1 (2)")
    Ws.Name = "Sheet1"

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Worksheets("Sheet4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Worksheets("Sheet5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Worksheets("Sheet6").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Worksheets("Sheet7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Worksheets("Sheet8").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Worksheets("Sheet9").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Worksheets("Sheet10").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
 
NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        
Call MAILDan
    
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ActiveWorkbook.Close

Kill "C:\Temp\*.xl*"
 
End Sub}
```

But this one on the server doesn't and stops at the copy/paste phase?

```
{Sub LatestUpdates()
 
    Dim FName           As String
    Dim FPath           As String
    Dim NewBook         As Workbook
    Dim Ws              As Worksheet
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 
    FPath = "S:\Shared Drive\That Folder\LatestUpdates"
    FName = "Latest Spreadsheet for Details" & " " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
 
    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
 
    **ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", "Sheet6", "Sheet7", _
        "Sheet8", "Sheet9", "Sheet10")).Copy Before:=NewBook.Sheets(1)**
        
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete
    Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1 (2)")
    Ws.Name = "Sheet1"

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Worksheets("Sheet4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Worksheets("Sheet5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Worksheets("Sheet6").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Worksheets("Sheet7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Worksheets("Sheet8").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Worksheets("Sheet9").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Worksheets("Sheet10").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
 
NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        
Call MAILDan
    
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ActiveWorkbook.Close

Kill "S:\Shared Drive\That Folder\LatestUpdates\*.xl*"
 
End Sub}
```

Any help as to why it wont work will be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: If you are creating a temporary workbook why not save it locally?

Comment: Not sure I can as the actual workbook is also on the shared server. I will however try tomorrow and see if I can. thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the workbook to a folder on the shared drive you could save it locally to the Temp folder.

The following code will do that, but you might need to adjust the code in **MAILDan** to refer to the correct path when attaching the new workbook to the email.

```
Sub LatestUpdates()
Dim NewBook As Workbook
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim FName As String
Dim FPath As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    FPath = GetTempFolder
    FName = "Latest Spreadsheet for Details" & " " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")

    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", "Sheet6", "Sheet7", _
                              "Sheet8", "Sheet9", "Sheet10")).Copy
                              
    Set NewBook = ActiveWorkbook
    
    For Each Ws In NewBook.Sheets
        Ws.Buttons.Delete
    Next Ws

    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

    NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

    Call MAILDan

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    FPath = NewBook.FullName#
    
    NewBook.Close

    Kill FPath

End Sub

Function GetTempFolder()
Dim FSO As Object, TmpFolder As Object

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set TmpFolder = FSO.GetSpecialFolder(2)
    GetTempFolder = TmpFolder

End Function
```

Comment: Many thanks norie, I will try this tomorrow and let you know. Also appreciate you showing me a tidier way to remove buttons.

Comment: Hi norie, after some small tweaking worked great. Just one question if I may? I used to be able to copy the Worksheets and save the individual sheet properties (not macro's) but these properties get cleared as well. Is there anyway to work this so it keeps these properties? Many thanks.

Comment: What properties are you referring to?

Comment: Hi norie, the Microsoft Excel Object for sheets e.g.Sheet1 (sheet1) that you can see from the VBA editor. As example {Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C40")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        SelectPayFreq.Show
    End If
End Sub}

Comment: If you mean the code the problem is that you are saving the new workbook as xlOpenXMLWorkbook, i.e. a workbook without macros enabled. You need to change xlOpenXMLWorkbook to xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled.